# INSERT SELECT query only specific rows

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Got this code for my sql command in C# for access.

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 (doctor_code, doctor_prclicense, doctor_hospacc) SELECT doctor_code, doctor_prclicense, doctor_hospacc FROM tbl1
```

The problem though is all I want is to copy specific row only. How should I do this? Can I use  `Count(*) = row2`?

Thanks!

This is want to fulfill.

in the column doctor_hospacc it has a string like @199@332@111

I want to split those string to get the numbers and omit the @ signs.
Now row 1 has doctor_code, doctor_prclicense and doctor_prclicense that contains "@199@332@111"

So This is want to do

[image]

The reason I want to get the row_number column so I can loop it. 
I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have `WHERE` clause in `SELECT` query to get specific rows based on `condition`

Example : `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID=11`

Try This: sample `INSERT INTO` command for gettng rows with `Doctor_Code` 11

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 (doctor_code, doctor_prclicense, doctor_hospacc) SELECT doctor_code,    
  doctor_prclicense, doctor_hospacc FROM tbl1 WHERE doctor_code=11
```

**Suggestion :** your query is open to `SQL injection attacks`, i would suggest you to use `parameterised sql queries` to avoid them.

Comment: That is correct; I would add to this, that you should probably use parameterized SQL to prevent possible SQL injection attacks

Comment: @Sudhakar Tillapudi thanks sir. But what I want is to get the row number. Because I want to loop it. Just like the row 1 will insert into to tbl2 3 times then the row 2 will insert 5 times. Just like that. Is it possible?

Comment: @LucasJuan: sorry i didnot get it could you please explain with some example?

Comment: @LucasJuan: you mean you want to get row number of `SELECT` Query?

Comment: @Sudhakar Tillapudi Yes sir, because that will be my basis for my loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can get row number by doing this :

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tbl1.ID) AS ROWNO, * FROM tbl1
```